# How to pass the return value of function with & operator in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

I came across following code snippet in ruby, where the safe navigation operator is used to call a second method, in the example below, does the response we get from Excon.get call passed to the process_json automatically. in the function definition of process_json ,there is no parameter being passed. I am not sure how this might work.

```
class Client
   API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.twitter.com'

   class << self
     def call
       new.call(API_ENDPOINT)&.process_json
     end
   end

   def call(url)
    Excon.get(url)
   end

   def process_json
    //process json response
   end 
end
```

Comment: Are you sure this code works? `Excon.get(some_url)` returns a response object with methods `body`, `headers`, `status` etc. What you have shown defines a `Client.process_json` method. It will not be called on the response from `Excon.get`. The `&.` operator is not very relevant to understanding how this code works.

Comment: @LesNightingill - 
I have edited the class. new.call(api_endpoint) , this works this will return the Excon::response object, but I wanted to see , if i can add a process_json method to process the response. and have such construct in my convenience method new.call(API_ENDPOINT)&.process_json

Comment: so... it's working now? It looks much better. BTW the `&.` operator is a shorthand, so that `method1&.method2` is the same as `method1 && method1.method2` or alternatively `method1 ? method1.method2 : nil`. It avoids `method2` being called when `method1` returns nil.